# Insert statement in production

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-6

I currently have an app working flawless locally. When I moved my application to production, I have been receiving the following error.

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table
'StarVote.dbo.Voters'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
statement has been terminated.
```

When I perform the action locally all works. Any idea why this may be happening? Whenever I create any object in my database, I get the error I listed above. My application allows me to create a user with built in Identity but my other objects seem to break my application. Locally works fine. Production fails.

Comment: Just check difference between Voters table in local db  and prod db.

Comment: out of all my crud operations. The create seems to not be working for any of my entities. What would maybe cause the create to not work live. Connection string? dbContext configuration? I know my connection string is working because i am reading objects which already exist in my database. let me know if you need me to provide a specific piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that `id` is supposed to be an incrementing value.

You need to set this, or else if you have a non-nullable column, with no default value, if you provide no value it will error.

To set up auto-increment in SQL Server Management Studio:

1. Open your table in Design
2. Select your column and go to Column Properties
3. Under Indentity Specification, set (Is Identity)=Yes and Indentity 
   Increment=1

Comment: This actually sounds legit. Thank you for responding i am going to try this and let you know. i see the updated values in my sql management studio when i perform an update action let me see if this fixes the create action.

Comment: You are amazing. It worked. I came from Ruby on Rails so i have never used Sql management Studio. Kind of stupid you have to set this for your tables. The id should clearly be auto incremented. Thank you for your help

Comment: @JustinWeinzimmer Welcome...please tick it as your solution on your left hand side...